# MYSQL insert infinite loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using that code to insert dummy data in a custom table using wordpress :

I'm currently working on local, using Mamp PRO, PHP 8.20, Mysql 5.7.39.

```
public function generateDummyData(){
        $localisations = $this->questions[0]['values'];
        $otherLocalisations = ['75015','17300','33000','44000','91100'];
        $answerTable = getAnswersTableName();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
            $localisation = $localisations[array_rand($localisations)]['value'];
            $type = 'salarie';
            $is_done = rand(0, 1) == 1 ? true : false;
            $updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', rand(strtotime('2023-08-01'), time()));
            $ip_address = '192.168.1.' . rand(1, 255);
            $this->wpdb->insert(
                $answerTable,
                [
                    'localisation' =>  $localisation,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'is_done' => $is_done,
                    'updated_at' => $updated_at,
                    'ip_address' => $ip_address
                ]
            );
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10, $i++;){
            $localisation = $otherLocalisations[array_rand($otherLocalisations)];
            $type = 'salarie';
            $is_done = rand(0, 1) == 1 ? true : false;
            $updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', rand(strtotime('2023-08-01'), time()));
            $ip_address = '192.168.1.' . rand(1, 255);
            $this->wpdb->insert(
                $answerTable,
                [
                    'localisation' =>  $localisation,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'is_done' => $is_done,
                    'updated_at' => $updated_at,
                    'ip_address' => $ip_address
                ]
            );
        }
        die;
    }
```

As you can see, i've accidentally made an infinite loop on `for ($i = 1; $i <= 10, $i++;)`.
I had an error 500 and that was it. But it kept creating rows in the table. Even after restarting MAMP, deleting / recreating the table, it was creating that dummy data.

Could it be that mysql caches some queries ? Or maybe PHP ? I don't really know it's kind of dark magic for me here. I thought it could be wpdb->insert() too, but it does not seems to be that.

I've rebooted Mamp, deleted/recreated the table, but the rows were still inserted.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the code until you make sure everything is corrected. The quries will not run on their own if not being executed somewhere.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yep i did that too. The only thing that worked was rebooting my computer.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes i did by rebooting and editing my code, but i'd like to know why it did that.

Comment: maybe your browser sent the request again (if you were testing it in a browser)

Comment: Do not reboot immediately.  restart after 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say where you put the code in your WordPress installation.

Still, most places you put php code (for example, in a plugin or in functions.php) cause that code to be run whenever a browser hits the installation for a page view. And, code is persistent: it goes into your machine's file system and is saved across reboots.

So, it seems likely your infinite loop got started again.

**Pro tip** Put a line of code like `error_log( 'inserting dummy data' );` at the top of stuff like this, then make sure you define [WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) in your development WordPress installations. Then you can look at `.../wp-content/debug.log` and find out your development code is hammering away.

Comment: I'm going to try your tip. I forgot to mention that i did commented the whole script inserting the dummy data. And it was still inserting. It was like a background job. I'll investigate more tomorrow. Thank you !